Where can I find brain scans of people who "changed their preferences" over time
 Hello, I hope this is the correct SE for my question. If not, Mods, please advise me where I need to go.
Background
Often people say, that they changed their preference with time. They dont eat certain type of food any more, because of reasons. They are desperate to establish that their dating preferences changed. Such changes are claimed to occur in many different facets of life.
I wonder
How deep are such changes? Can we quantitatively measure the biochemical signatures behind such changes?
My idea
Would it therefore be possible to see, by the means of brain scan, how much actual measurable difference such changes account to? Or whether these changes are sort of a "modulation" of a person's true preference.
Specifically, let us consider scenario A:
Alice used to drink a lot of cheap liquor in her 20s. In her 30s, she says her "drinking preferences" changed, and she only drinks high end branded goods.
I am assuming that we can find via an MRI scan of 20 year old Alice, that there are different areas on her brain that light up, that correspond to

the desire to drink, and
to the cheap liquor

Later, by repeating the same experiment with 30 year old Alice, we find the areas that light up are:

same areas corresponding to the desire to drink, as it was in her 20s
areas corresponding to high end branded goods
some memories or something else that "modulates" her changing behavior

However, the areas corresponding to cheap liquor do not light up any more
Consider also scenario B: Her dating preferences changed. I also assume that we can also see such shifts in MRI scan by repeating the same experiment with 20 year old and 30 year old Alice, with areas corresponding to desire to date, the type of men she date in her 20s, and the type of men she wants in her 30s, and her memories.
Of course there are Ethical and Technological considerations. Let's put ethics at the side now for this specific question.
EXACT question
Assuming such experiments have already been performed, where can I find open source MRI scan data about or similar to the situations I mentioned above, that I can feed in an image classifier AI that can identify and quantify such shifts?
Thank you.

How would you see what areas "light up" using an MRI?

If you scan someone's brain 10 years later and try to estimate some differences, your measurement will include all of the differences that accumulated over 10 years, plus any error in your estimates ("noise").
If you want to focus in on one specific difference, you can't identify it in one scan. You might be able to find it if you have a huge population of people, all with scans at two times, and all that had the same feature that changed over that time. You would also need to be able to factor out other variables, like the general passage of time, perhaps by having people in your sample that changed in the opposite direction, so you can look for your one difference without more general effects of, say, aging.
You would also need to deal with other types of confounding; if someone changed their mind about desire to drink, how do you know that changes you see in the brain are related to changes in that desire and not caused by actual alcohol consumption?
I doubt you would see a detectable effect like you are describing, and certainly no one has the data set you would need already.

Ok, so such a dataset does not exist right now, that's a pity, but thank you.

@Sean I hope that's not all you got out of my answer...

no no, i also understood that the variable separation would be a difficult task.

@Sean I think it would be downright impossible. Take your example. An incredible number of confounding variables happen in 10 years. Even if minor behavioral changes like you describe cause gross changes in brain activity (which I highly doubt), how would you know which changes are due to what causes? I'm pretty sure no one has identified regions of the brain responsible for specific preferences, and I also doubt that things like that have their own piece of neural real estate. If they did, a hell of a lot of brain tissue would be dedicated to all of life's individual choices.
